# Login form based spring 3 security

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication login.
I want to pass the dynamic value in name and password but i don't want to use service layer, for this i am using web-service call in controller.

Here is my code :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">    

                <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
                 <http pattern="/auth/logout.html" security="none"/>
                 <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
                 <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" /> 

                <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
                <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
                <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/suburb_analyser" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
                <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
            </http>

            <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
                <authentication-provider>
                    <user-service>
                        <user name="j@hotsal.com.au" password="mor55eover" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                    </user-service>
                </authentication-provider>
            </authentication-manager>

        </beans:beans>
```

Comment: Did you mean to include a password in this post?

Comment: In this line   <user name="j@hotsal.com.au" password="mor55eover" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> I want to use the dynamic name and password in place of "name="j@hotsal.com.au" password="mor55eover" "

Comment: I understand what you're asking in your question. I'm wondering if you use `mor55eover` as a password. If so, a) you should not have posted it here and b) since you have, you should immediately change that password anywhere you use it.

Comment: sorry  you means   <user name="" password="" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> If i remove name and password from here then its give compilation time error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the dynamic value in name and password. You need to declare a bean that implement [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) interface. Then modify your xml to:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="yourServiceBeanName">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

You can use JDBC,File System or Memory to generate your name and password dynamically in your service.